# clang matchers. find the corresponding node in ast by translation unit, line number, and column

Tags: c++, clang

hello and thx in advance for your help.

i recently made some efforts to understand the clang matching system and got stuck on a specific problem.

having a source file in an editor with a cursor set to a position in a line, thus having a precise location, is there a way to find, and return, the corresponding node in the clang ast by this information?

as user scenario think of me clicking into the code in an editor and identifing the exact node and type of node from the corresponding ast.

i think it is in some way possible using a visitor, but can i use the matching mechanism too?

i studied the given matchers, but i don't seem to get anywhere...

thx

frithjofh

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with matchers. You should look into [cursors](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__SOURCE.html).

Comment: @Benjamin Bannier: many thx for the answer. i had totally overlooked that. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I wasn't aware of cursors, thanks to Benjamin for pointing me in the right direction.
See [cursors](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__SOURCE.html) for the function clang_getCursor which, providing it with a precise location in source code, returns the corresponding cursor into the AST, which then can be queried for kind, name, children, and location of the referred to node.
Sorry too for my English, i am not a native speaker.
Greetings too to the sad, sorry, and bitter lad who down voted my question without even stating any reason. That is ever so encouraging for new comers like me.